# Grid colouring game : Find the number of red and blue lines drawn

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem Description: Walter has a grid of size N*M , initially each of the cell is white . Walter can draw a horizontal or vertical stroke which can be 1 or more cell long. Walter only draws horizontal stroke with RED colour and Vertical stroke with BLUE color Walter never draws two horizontal or two vertical stroke overlapping. If a horizontal stroke crosses vertical stroke then color of the cell is Green. Given the string having the color patter of cells , find the number of red and blue strokes required to achieve it .

Input : {"GRG","BGW","WWW"}  OP: 2 Red and 3 Blue stroke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class GridColouring {

    public static int getStrokes(String [] grid) {
        int N = grid.length;
        int M = grid[0].length();
        HashSet<Integer> hr = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Integer> v = new HashSet<>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String row = grid[i];
            row = row.toUpperCase();
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                // Precedence of 'and' greater than 'or'
                if (row.charAt(j) == 'G' || (row.charAt(j) == 'R' && !hr.contains(i))) {
                    hr.add(i);

                } else if (hr.contains(i)) {
                    if (j > 0 && grid[i].charAt(j - 1) == 'B') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (row.charAt(j) == 'G' || (row.charAt(j) == 'B' && !v.contains(j))) {
                    v.add(j);
                } else if(v.contains(j)) {

                    if (i > 0 && grid[i-1].charAt(j) == 'R') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int horStrokes = hr.size();
        int verStrokes = v.size();

        int minStrokes = horStrokes + verStrokes + count;
        return minStrokes;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String [] a = {"GR.","BG.","RBR","BBB"};
        System.out.println(getStrokes(a));
    }
}
```

Output : 8

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what dynamic programming adds to this.

Make each contiguous line of red or green pixels a horizontal stroke.

Make each contiguous column of blue or green pixels a vertical stroke.

Count the total number of strokes. This reproduces the initial pattern, and is the minimum number of strokes required: each stroke extends as far as it can without contradicting the data.